# JSF show thrown message in h:message

Tags: java, jsf, exception

i searched everywhere and i'm trying everything, no success with a real exception..

i need to throw an exception so it 'ignore' everything after the method point (a single return wouldn't be enough cuz there are more methods above) so I found something like this:

```
throw new javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ex instanceof ValidationException ? ex.getMessage() : MessageProvider.getMessage("sales.insert.error"), null));
```

**EDIT 1**
(This is done inside a `void method` in my `ManagedBean` (@ViewScoped), the method is called from a `p:commandButton` with a `action="#{something}"`.

**EDIT 2**
The button:

```
<p:commandLink id="finalizarBtn" action="#{vendaMB.finalizarVenda()}"  update="@form" process="@this, vendaList" styleClass="btn btn-regalo margin-side-5 btn-block" title="#{msg['sales.add']}" style="width: 500px; display: inline-block; margin: 20px 0px;" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-2x fa-check"></i></p:commandLink>
```

And the complete method:

```
public void finalizarVenda() throws ValidatorException {
    if(vendaProdutos.size() < 1) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("vendaForm:produto", "");
        return;
    }
    venda.setDataVenda(new Date());
    try {
        venda = vendaBO.incluir(venda, vendaProdutos);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        venda.setDataVenda(null);
        vendaBO.getDB().rollbackTransaction();
        throw new javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ex instanceof ValidationException ? ex.getMessage() : MessageProvider.getMessage("sales.insert.error"), null));
    }
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("sales.insert.success"));
    novaVenda();
}
```

The messages component:

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" escape="false" rendered="true" closable="true" />
```

i use this inside my try/catch block, it throws the exception as expected (the message) but it's never rendered at the view, if i manually add the `FacesMessage` to the `FacesContext` and throw the exception that is being catch, the same happens, no error messages at the view, example:

```
try {
  //something
} catch (Exception ex) {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("something"));
  throw ex;
}
```

Both solutions doesn't work, i'm using JSF, PrimeFaces and Tomcat 8.

Comment: Where are you throwing this `ValidatorException`?

Comment: oh sorry, in my `ManagedBean` after i press a button in the screen, in a actionListener.

Comment: So the problem is for a misconception of actionListener (which usually happens to newcomers of JSF). Check here: [Differences between action and actionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267/1065197) and read the accepted answer, it covers the reason of your problem and how to solve it.

Comment: sorry sorry, again, huh, i'm using action in this method, i'll add in the question the following code.

Comment: Please update the question and add all the relevant content to reproduce this problem so we could provide a solution.

Comment: Uh... do you at least have a `<h:messages>` (or `<p:messages>`) inside your `<h:form>`?

Comment: af course, didn't expect it to be so relevant, i'll put it in the question...

Comment: Again: put all the necessary code **to reproduce the problem** in your question. Maybe you have some very specific configuration/stuff that makes this fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54739/discussion-between-simego-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a ValidatorException from your managed bean will not set the message. 
Will the following work:

```
public void finalizarVenda() throws ValidatorException {
    if(vendaProdutos.size() < 1) {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("vendaForm:produto", "");
        return;
    }
    venda.setDataVenda(new Date());
    try {
        venda = vendaBO.incluir(venda, vendaProdutos);
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage(MessageProvider.getMessage("sales.insert.success"));
        novaVenda();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        venda.setDataVenda(null);
        vendaBO.getDB().rollbackTransaction();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ex instanceof ValidationException ? ex.getMessage() : MessageProvider.getMessage("sales.insert.error"), null));
    }
}
```

If the `novaVenda()` method can also throw an exception you might also want to wrap that in a try catch block and throw the caught exception.